# Blazor, use Fabric-js controls

Tags: blazor

Is there a way to use Fabric JS controls https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric-js inside Blazor?

I tried to put things together, but I've some issues, e.g. dropdown select controls does not bind correctly.

I've also found this one: https://github.com/BlazorExtensions/BlazorOfficeUIFabric

but is not updated since 9 months

Comment: folks here expect you to relate to answers they provided for your questions. We are not your employees.

Comment: I apologize, but I just asked if someone has already tried this, not to do some work for me.

Comment: Is this yours? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56134234/blazor-component-twoway-databinding

Comment: Issac, pardon me, I've not answered yet because I'm checking it out, I've some more issues and thoughs I'd like to share about it soon.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, that set of controls had potential, but like you said had no work on it for months.

But you should come and help me with my own port...
https://github.com/limefrogyank/BlazorFabric

I even have a demo page for the "working" controls.
https://blazorfabric.azurewebsites.net/

It's definitely not a 1-for-1 port.  There are things not working because either I didn't need them or they were too complicated just to get this out of the door.  Some of it is even on NuGet but I haven't updated those with preview8 yet.  Working on it now.